# Java Android - cropping Image in ImageView

Tags: java, android, imageview, crop

I know this should be simple , but `android:scaleType="centerCrop"` doesn't crop Image

I got image *1950 pixels* wide and need it to be cropped by parent's width. But `android:scaleType="centerCrop"` dosen't crop Image. What do I need to do in layout to show only first *400 pixels*, for instance or whatever screen/parent width is

Sorry for simple question - tried to google it - only complicated questions there. And I'm new, so dont downvote plz)

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/rl1"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="@color/background_color">

    <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/ver_bottompanelprayer"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="227px"
            android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
            android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
            android:scaleType="matrix"

            android:background="@drawable/ver_bottom_panel_tiled_long" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

Answer (score 1):

Try adding `android:adjustViewBounds="true"` to your `ImageView` together with `android:scaleType` property

Comment: doesn't change anything - it tries to fit all the 1950 pixels into ImageView

Comment: @user2234594 what is your `ImageView`s `layout_width` parameter?

Comment: android:layout_width="match_parent" fill_parent doesn't change a thing

Answer (score 1):

Use   `android:scaleType="matrix"` for your imageview

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/opLayout"
    android:layout_width="400px"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/bar"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:scaleType="matrix"
        android:src="@drawable/ic_launcher_web" />

</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: sorry, that doesn't crop my image. Still it tries to fit the entire big image

Comment: Can you post your xml

Comment: Are you using  android:src to set your image